# What is the difference between : " I turned around and saw X" and " I was turning around and saw X" ( Simple past vs past continous)

Tags: grammar, past-tense, simple-past, logic

I would assume the difference is minor, in the former I finished the action of turning around and then saw X. In the latter I saw X while turning around. However one would certainly stop turning, when one sees a familiar face. It would be ridiculous to keep on turning. So the logic in the latter case is somewhat flawed. In addition the use of "and" in the latter case is a mistake, isn't it?

Comment: Who says you would stop turning? If I was turning around to address X, and I saw Y, I would still turn all the way to address X.

Comment: So you agree to my assumptions until that point ? @oerkelens

Comment: 'Context is everything' as someone once said. If you're doing a manoeuvre during a driving lesson, which can be way other than punctive, "I was turning around and saw X” may be exactly what you want. But I'd say that bodily turning round is usually approximated to as a punctive event, so I'd use 'I turned around and saw X' even if I merely caught a glimpse when I'd completed 1/3 of the 180 degrees.

Comment: It would depend on the intention you had when turning around, even if you stopped turning when you saw X. For example "I was turning around to look at the sea when I saw Mary, we ran to each other and kissed" as opposed to "I heard the sound of a gun being cocked, I turned around and saw Blofeld pointing a revolver in my direction". In the first case your intention changes when you see a loved one in passing, in the second you complete the action before realising that you are being threatened by a cricket commentator with a gun.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we use "ing" form of verbs (continues or progressive form) to say that we were doing something while another action takes place. EG. I was taking a bath when the telefon rang.

I turned around and saw Mr.X - Simple Past

I was turning around when she asked me. - Progressive

Only "Stative Verbs" as, like, love, agree, and some others would not be used in ing (progressive form) cause they are states/stative and not dynamic.